# Missing Workspace and Builder action links in a Digital Experience deployed via an ExperienceBundle in a scratch org

Tags: community, salesforcedx, digital-experience, experience-bundle

Deploying an existing Digital Experience into a new scratch org this morning is hitting the problem normally addressed like this [Add a Digital Experience site member if either the 'Manage' or 'Workspaces' link is not available](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387677&type=1) i.e. adding a `NetworkMemberGroup` record to make the SA a member of the Digital Experience. But in my case that record is already present with the correct `AssignmentStatus` of "Added".

I've done several deployments - had to revert some changes - and they all have the same problem. Creating an experience locally - the "fake" one below - works. I'm using automation to deploy via [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) metadata.

Any ideas on what to do to fix this?

**PS**

First org still broken. Just created a new scratch org and it took a few minutes before they appear but the links did appear.

[image: screen shot of experiences]

Comment: This is where using perm set membership is ideal since you can add this to selective users, including sys admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first org is still broken. I created a new scratch org and it took a few minutes after the Digital Experience was deployed before the links appeared but they did appear.

So looks looks a once-off problem.